# Configure lint to ignore error "No `.class` files were found"

Tags: android, maven, lint, android-maven-plugin

I am using [android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) to build my android project. I have enabled lint when building my android project. I got the following lint error:

```
No `.class` files were found in project &quot;main&quot;, so none of the classfile based checks could be run. Does the project need to be built first?
```

Lint message explained that this is an error of running lint itself, not an error of my project code.

My question is, is it possible to configure lint to silently ignore this specific error (but keep notifying other warnings/errors)? How to do it?

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <id>lint</id>
              <goals>
                 <goal>lint</goal>
              </goals>
              <phase>install</phase>
          </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
          <sdk>
             <platform>17</platform>
          </sdk>
          <lint>
             <skip>false</skip>
             <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          </lint>
      </configuration>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you run the command

```
mvn install
```

since the class files are generated in the earlier compile phase.